# C# - only first if gets executed (XNA/Keypress)

Tags: c#, monogame

I am making my own input system in Monogame program, and for now 
I have a problem with if statments here:

```
public static void Input()
    {
        if (IsKeyPressed(Keys.Space))
        {
            Cursor.X += 25;
        }

        if (IsKeyPressed(Keys.Back))
        {
            Words.Last().RemoveLetter();
            Cursor.X -= 25;
        }

        if (IsKeyPressed(Keys.A))
        {
            Words.Last().AddLetter(new Letter(Letters.A, Cursor));
            Cursor.X += 25;
        }
    }

static bool IsKeyPressed(Keys key)
    {
        keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(key) && prevKeyState.IsKeyUp(key))
        {
            prevKeyState = keyState;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            prevKeyState = keyState;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Okay so in my method Input I check for keypresses, and the result in program is that whichever key I put in first IF statment, that key will work, so if I change 'A' where the 'Space' is now, A would work and Space wouldn't...

Why are other ifs always false ?

**EDIT:**

Okay so actually, if my IsKeyPressed() method looks like this (without prevKeyState variable):

```
   static bool IsKeyPressed(Keys key)
    {
        keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

then it works :/ but I need that preKeyState variable because I want to, no matter how long I hold for example, A key to just print one letter a, until I release that key :/

Comment: Not sure if this will fix anything, but you probably want these keys to be mutually exclusive, so it would be best to turn those `if`s into `else if`s.

Comment: tried it, didn't change anything

Comment: Keep it that way. It solves other issues you've yet to realize (for example, what if someone presses `A` *and* `Space` at the same time?)

Comment: @RenéVogt that was spelling error sorry, it is keystate.IsKeyDown()

Answer (score 0):

Had an similar issue. Solved it by passing the new and old KeyboardState to the function. Ended with something like this which works fine.

```
public void HandleKeyStroke(KeyboardState ks, KeyboardState oldks)
{
    if (ks.IsKeyDown(GameplayButtons.ACTIONBAR_0) && oldks.IsKeyUp(GameplayButtons.ACTIONBAR_0))
        UIManager.actionToBeTriggered("actionbar_0");
    if (ks.IsKeyDown(GameplayButtons.ACTIONBAR_1) && oldks.IsKeyUp(GameplayButtons.ACTIONBAR_1))
        UIManager.actionToBeTriggered("actionbar_1");
    if (ks.IsKeyDown(GameplayButtons.ACTIONBAR_2) && oldks.IsKeyUp(GameplayButtons.ACTIONBAR_2))
        UIManager.actionToBeTriggered("actionbar_2");
    if (ks.IsKeyDown(GameplayButtons.ACTIONBAR_3) && oldks.IsKeyUp(GameplayButtons.ACTIONBAR_3))
        UIManager.actionToBeTriggered("actionbar_3");
    if (ks.IsKeyDown(GameplayButtons.CHARACTER) && oldks.IsKeyUp(GameplayButtons.CHARACTER))
        UIManager.ToggleWindowById("button_Character");
}
```

There is probably some cleaner solution, especially if you have more buttons to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it wasn't hard to fix this I just didn't think of it, but
hetting KeyboardStates in Input method instead of IsKeyPressed bool method fixes everything:

```
static bool IsKeyPressed(Keys key)
    {
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(key) && prevKeyState.IsKeyUp(key))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void Input()
    {
        keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (IsKeyPressed(Keys.Space))
        {
            Cursor.X += 25;
        }

        else if (IsKeyPressed(Keys.Back))
        {
            Words.Last().RemoveLetter();
            Cursor.X -= 25;
        }

        else if (IsKeyPressed(Keys.A))
        {
            Words.Last().AddLetter(new Letter(Letters.A, Cursor));
            Cursor.X += 25;
        }

        prevKeyState = keyState;
    }
```

I'm not quiet sure what difference does it makes, if someone can explain in detail that would be awsome

PS. I can't upvote anyone because of my low reputation, but thanks everyone for sharing your thoughts it was helpful